# Why is this matrix positive semi-definite?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, matrices

Given a Linear Time-Invariant system $\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t)+B$, $A\in Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$, $x,B \in \mathbb R^n$ defined on the time interval $[0,t_f]$, we define the **Controllability Gramian** as follows:

$W(t_f)=\int_{0}^{t_f}e^{-A\tau}BB^Te^{-A^T\tau}d\tau$.

It is not difficult to see that it is symmetric. But another property of this Controllability Gramian is that it is positive semi=definite, meaning:

for every vector $v\in \mathbb R^n$: $v^TW(t_f)v \geq 0$.

I am struggling to understand why this is true, especially since we don't know anything about $A$ or $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the integral of a non-negative function? Note that $v^{T}BB^{T}v$ is non-negative for all $v$.

Comment: The integral of a non negative function is non negative, that's not what's bothering me. What I don't understand is why is $v^TBB^Tv \geq 0 $ for all $v$? We know nothing about the eigenvalues of $BB^T$, maybe it has a negative eigenvalue and it is not positive semi-definite.

Comment: Nevermind, got it. $v^TBB^Tv = (B^Tv)^T(B^Tv)$ which is an inner product of a vector and itself, which is not negative.